# creating and reading an excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to create and read data from excel , but when I try to build the common code I found for it , it does not recognize the Excel objects. 
I have tried to open a new project - same problem there when it is a library but in console application it compiles fine.

what am I doing wrong?

added the code i have tried from here http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/696864/Working-with-Excel-Using-Csharp? :

```
MyApp = new Excel.Application();
MyApp.Visible = false;
MyBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open(DB_PATH);
MySheet = (Excel.Worksheet)MyBook.Sheets[1]; // Explicit cast is not required here
lastRow = MySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row;
```

Comment: Your code snippet will shed some light on your question.

Comment: Agree, show us the pertinent code.

Comment: MyApp = new Excel.Application();
MyApp.Visible = false;
MyBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open(DB_PATH);
MySheet = (Excel.Worksheet)MyBook.Sheets[1]; // Explicit cast is not required here
lastRow = MySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row;

Comment: Lol @MoriyaSamun edit your post, don't put your code in a comment.

Comment: sorry I am kind of new here . now I have added it in to my post!

Comment: Did you add `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` as reference to your project ?